# Forbid access to directory, but not alias?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, apache2.4

Using Apache. How can I allow access to /storage/ but deny access to /.storage/ when /storage/ is an alias for /.storage/subdomain/?

```
# Define alias based on subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^storage/(.*)$ ".storage/%1/$1" [QSA,L]

# Forbid access to 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.storage/
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. We need to fix regex for getting sub-domain first then we need to change `"` from rules and add an additional condition to checks to make sure users are not able to access actual folder directly.

```
RewriteEngine ON
# Define alias based on subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/(.*)$ .storage/%1/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# Forbid access to 
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^\.storage - [F,NC,L]
```